# Asking employer to change salary account

Tags: english-to-german

Is this correctly written in German? I'm asking my employer the process to change salary account to a new account.

"Was ist der Prozess, um das Gehaltskonto in Ihre System zu ändern. Ich habe kürzlich ein Konto bei VR bank eröffnet."

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. So you have a new bank account and the bank account currently used by your employer is the old and needs to be changed to the new one? So what let's you struggle with your current proposal? (this site offers some help with specific language problems, not with a translation - and your question right now is plain translation)

Comment: Your translation contains errors and seems rather unidiomatic. But understandable.

Comment: Yes that's correct old account needs to be replaced to new account. How do your write this correctly without translation?

Comment: Without translation I stick to English? I meant you need to rewrite your question to ask your specific problem you have with your proposal and _not_ asking only for a full translation to German. It is great that you have a proposal. So let's keep going to where you struggle - in detail.

Comment: My proposal is not correct grammatically, how would you write this if you had to ask your employer to change your bank account in their system?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there was no rewriting why OP thinks it is wrong, no options to choose from (in case it is to hard to describe why it feels wrong). etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the wording, the three errors are:

- *in Ihre**m** System*: the preposition *in* requires the *Dativ*
- *zu ändern **?***: Every question ends with a question mark, not with a full stop.
- *bei **der VR-Bank** eröffnet*: with an article, hyphen and capitalized.

However, asking for the process sounds very, very odd. This kind of technocratic speech isn't common at all in German (it sounds like a literal translation of American business english). Instead you could say it like this:

1. If they'll change it for you, just tell them your new bank details:

> Meine neue Bankverbindung lautet: IBAN DE12 3456 7890 1234 5678 90

2. If you really have to change it yourself, you can directly ask how to do it:

> Wie kann ich meine neue Bankverbindung ins System [or: im Intranet/bei *$name_of_the_system*] eingeben?

Both sound a lot better stylistically. Just remember: direct phrasing of your concern is the key, the less technical the better.

Comment: Thanks amadeusamadeus 